# Highcharts:column range chart not showing label when data is 100

Tags: highcharts

Take a look at the below column range chart:

http://jsfiddle.net/AnAZF/
In the above chart if the data is 100, the value does not appear. This occurs only in firefox.But it works fine in chrome.Is there some configuration missing?

Comment: Which version of Firefox?

Comment: This is seen right from 4.0 upto version 22.

Comment: Could you attach screenshots? Cause in my 22 (macosx) version it works well.